# "Device not ready" on a network share in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, network-share, troubleshooting

I have two computers C1 and C2 runing Windows 7 and both of them are members in a domain. On C1 I have an USB hard-disk which I shared for the users U1 and U2 giving them Read-Only permissions on the entire drive.

However, even if I can see and browse the hard-disk localy (IOW from C1), from the other computer (C2) where I'm logged with U1, trying to access the C1's shared device, the C2's Windows 7 throws an error saying "Device Not Ready". Why? How can I fix this?

PS: Tried to un-share and re-share again. No luck.

Comment: Its a USB drive? Have you tried to safely remove it and unplug it and restart the computer? Then reconnect it and try to share it again? Sometimes these little things help on windows. You could also try the advance sharing rather than the normal sharing - or the other way around. Put the permissions on groups rather than on single users. Thats what I would try first.

Comment: @Richard: Clean/Full restart the computer did it. The old trick. Pls post your comment as an answer in order to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a USB drive? Have you tried to safely remove it and unplug it and restart the computer? Then reconnect it and try to share it again? Sometimes these little things help on windows. You could also try the advance sharing rather than the normal sharing - or the other way around. Put the permissions on groups rather than on single users. Thats what I would try first.